# What does the @ symbol mean next to the permissions in Terminal?

Tags: permissions, terminal, symbols

I’m in the process of making a website so I downloaded a JavaScript file from the internet and added it to my project directory. I needed to change the permissions of this file because I was getting a 403 error. When I looked at the permissions of the file I noticed there was an `@` character next to the `-rwxr-xr-x` part e.g. `-rwxr-xr-x@` (I would have liked to have posted an image but I need 10 reputation :/). Can somebody explain to me what this `@` symbol signifies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer myself on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine):

> This attribute is added so that it can ask for user confirmation the first time the downloaded program is run, to help stop malware. Upon confirmation the attribute should be removed and then the program will run normally.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l), it's to denote additional extended attributes on a file system.